# How a Java SE application can connect to JBoss MQ?

Tags: java, jboss, jms, jbossmq

I have looked in the JBoss documentation, I have googled, but I can't find a sample code
to connect to the JBoss MQ from a JAVA SE application.

Do you have some link to share or better some sample code ?

**JBoss 5.1.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest example I could find was

http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r4/html/ch6.chapt.html

Which doesn't look at that simple to me. ;)

I have always found ActiveMQ simpler http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html  Perhaps there should be simpler example for JBoss MQ.

Comment: Can Java Chronicle be an alternative to JBossMQ ?

Comment: @Stephan It can but it's not a JMS service.  It's designed for ultra high performance e.g. latencies around one micro-second with no garbage created, which means some things which are simpler in JMS, such as Serialization, are not so simple with Java Chronicle.  It now has better support for messaging over TCP. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/high-performance-durable-messaging.html  The serialization is not much more complicated than using Externalizable BTW.